# Open a popup window on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have one form in JSP. I have some input fields in that page, when user types his values then he clicks submit so that values will be inserted into the database.

But my purpose is that when user clicks submit button then one new popup window will be generated and this new popup window will carry those values at the time of inserted values in parent window. Ex: first page: Insert.jsp and popup window: Verifyinsert.jsp. In Insert.jsp page 3 input fields are present such as roll number, student name, address. User will enter these 3 fields first on Insert.jsp page and then user will click submit on Insert.jsp page, then one new popup window(Verifyinsert.jsp) will be generated carrying values when user just has typed in Insert.jsp and in that Verifyinsert.jsp page, submit button is present and if user clicks submit then records will be inserted into database and if cancel button will be clicked on Verifyinsert.jsp then that popup window will be simply disappeared. How to do it?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: only enclose the call to the jsp into the window.open sentence saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [onSubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp) event

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function greeting(){
                alert("Welcome " + document.forms["frm1"]["fname"].value + "!")
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        What is your name?<br />
        <form name="frm1" action="submit.htm" onsubmit="greeting()">
            <input type="text" name="fname" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok but how can i add cancel button in popup window so that after clicking cancel simply i will return to my parent window?

Comment: this you can handle with Javascript code. if you return false on onSubmit, you cancel the submit, so you can create a popup and handle the new submit and the cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to show popup window? Should it be js popup, with no page reload, or separate browser tab? For former we use jqModal library, [examples](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples). When user clicks on Submit button you need to display that popoup. When user clicks on Send button on that popup you need to get all values and send them to the server. There are a couple of way to do that too :)

Comment: popup window is generating like this: <input type="button" value="Save"onClick="window.open('Verifyinsert.jsp','mywindow','width=500,height=350,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,menubar=yes')" title="Click here to insert details" /> How will transfer the values of insert.jsp to Verifyinsert.jsp page? When user types rollno, name and address of a student in insert.jsp then after clicking this submit button on insert.jsp page then a new popup window is generating but how can i transfer values of rollno, student name and address to Verifyinsert.jsp page from insert.jsp page?

Comment: M, a couple of ways, but they all are kind of tricky :) You could add event listener to Save button and wait while page is opened and transfer data to new window. Or in Verify window, somewhere in onload event you could get data from parent window (seems simpler, `window.opener` as @Abhi suggested). May be you could customize `onclick` event of button and use @Abhi method.

Comment: ya in @Abhi method...for multiple input fields inside form, i am getting error in javascript.   <script type="text/javascript">
            function greeting(){
                alert("Welcome " + document.forms["frm1"]["fname"].value + "!")
               
            }
        </script>

Answer (score 0):

Open a popup window in the submit of your  Insert.jsp using

```
   window.open("../insert.jsp?param1=xx&&pram2=cc")
```

you can send the parameters as append to the url of new window like above.

In the submit of Verifyinsert.jsp , you can call a parent page java script usign

```
window.opener.saveValue()
```

which is a javscript function in your parent page to save values to database .
Close your popup after saving .